# Created in vimrc variable is not seen in terminal, but only in gui version?

Tags: vim

I use the nightly build of VIM 8.1.565. It comes as both a terminal `vim.exe` and gui `gvim.exe` version.

If I create a variable in my _vimrc I can echo it only from the gui version `gvim.exe`. When I run `vim.exe` in a terminal there's no that variable, it doesn't see it.

Why is that? What am I missing here?

PS I have several vims on my system (in the path). One that I mentioned above and another as a cygwin package. They have different version number, so when I run it in a terminal I can see that it's the vim I need. So, there's no mistake here.

Comment: Can you issue the ex command, `:echo $MYVIMRC`, for both the gui and the command line?  This should at least confirm to you which vimrc file is being used for both.  Also, FWIW, `:help initialization`, is a pretty good read.

Comment: @Patrick Bacon Yes, I was wrong (Obveously!). Those are different vims. I ruled out the cygwin one. But I didn't consider that I may have had the two instances of the same version of vim in both places, which was exactly the case. Thank you so much! PS Patrick, could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Leverage Vim's Initialization Process by Checking the Value of $MYVIMRC**

When I look at the help files associated with initialization, e.g. `:help initialization`, it states:

> The $MYVIMRC or $MYGVIMRC file will be set to the first found vimrc
>   and/or gvimrc file.

This will help in clarifying which vimrc is being called for both the gui and the command line.

I have had a similar problem (I also do most of my work on a windows computer and I also leverage cygwin for some of its applications).

Section 3 of the initialization section discusses vim's process associated with looking for and executing the vimrc file.

> Places for your personal initializations:
>       ...       MS-Windows  $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
>                 or $VIM/_vimrc

There is great value in understanding this process. I place my vimrc file at $HOME/_vimrc and my cygwin and non-cygwin version of vim use the same _vimrc.